# Javascript on mobile sites: Is it OK to use click?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm creating a mobile version for my sites, and I was wondering: is it ok to keep all the click events in the javascript as they are, or should I change it to tap (for example [tap.js](http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2012/03/12/tap-js-a-lightweight-tap-event-javascript-plugin/))

I've noticed that click works in all the browsers that I tested (Native, Dolphin and Chrome on Galaxy S2). Do you know of any issues in keeping the click events?

Comment: "It also falls back to using regular mouse events when touch is not supported, so you don't need to manually feature detect or provide two different event types in your code."

Sounds to me it can come in handy, but haven't seen any problems with click on mobile devices so far myself.

Comment: The downside to `click` is the delay you have to deal with. On iOS it's about 300ms because the browser waits for a `double tap` before executing the `click` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile browsers are designed to work with most sites out of the box, thus they implement the click event just as desktop browser.

However, as *Torsten Walter* explained you might induce a noticeable delay if you don't explicitly manage the tap events.

To make it short : click will work but managing tap too will improve touchscreen user experience.